# Meaning of "go cards-up on something"

Tags: expressions, slang

I've seen this expression in an episode of Supernatural TV series:

> "Do it, or I go cards-up on your whole clambake"

For me it seems he intends to tell the others about "the clambake" unless they do what he is demanding.

But after some googling I could not find any clue to what this expression means and its origins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard this expression before and I can't find any reference to it on google, so I am guessing it's not a specific expression.

Going cards-up would be akin to playing a game (probably poker) with your cards facing up, basically saying you're not afraid to do something and you don't care if people know that you are responsible for it.

Clambake is another word for a type of social gathering, it is used here probably for the alliteration with 'cards-up'. It sounds like he is saying do something or I will openly tell everyone about your plans for some kind of event.

Comment: What if going cards-up means "to reveal something", as when poker players turn their cards up at the end of each turn?

Comment: Didn't know about the clambake one. But in this case they also talk about a buffet and steamers, so maybe they meant clams literally ;)